How to read `DeclaringType` from `JsonPropertyTypeInfo` in System.Text.Json?
I want to customize serialization based on the type of the property. To do that I would like to read DeclaringType from JsonPropertyInfo. This is an example from Microsoft documentation on how to create such a modifier
    // Custom modifier that increments the value
        // of a specific property on deserialization.
        static void IncrementCounterModifier(JsonTypeInfo typeInfo)
        {
            foreach (JsonPropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeInfo.Properties)
            {
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType != typeof(int))
                    continue;

The DeclaringType property is not available directly on JsonPropertyInfo though unfortunately (for some strange reason it is defined as internal), but on a generic type that inherits from it. Is there a way without reflection to read it in modifier?

Can you not use Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) I think then you could pass the contract and the object and it has a declaringype.

It is possible that it is easier there, I would like to stick to STJ though if it can done there

seems that it is on .NET8+ - docs

Prior to .NET 8 you can get the MemberInfo from the AttributeProvider simply by trying to cast it using as: public static MemberInfo? GetMemberInfo(this JsonPropertyInfo property) => (property.AttributeProvider as MemberInfo);.  See e.g. this answer to How to implement custom JsonConverter based on property names?.  From there you can get DeclaringType.  Is that what you need?
